# Iterated Pi function

Tags: prime-numbers

Does anyone have any information on iterating the prime counting function. Specifically, $\pi_n(x)$=$\pi(\pi_{n-1}(x))$, and $\pi_1(x)$=$\pi(x)$. I'm looking for anything on this function, what it may be called (when I search for iterate pi function, all I get is information about calculating pi).

Comment: Searching the OEIS gets you [this](http://oeis.org/A132090) although there doesn't appear to be much information.

Comment: @JackM: Also [A007097](https://oeis.org/A007097), where a(n) is the least number such that $\pi_n(a(n))=1.$

Answer (score 2):

$\pi_n(x)\sim\frac{x}{\log^nx}$ for any fixed $n$, though this estimate will be too large if $n$ is allowed to grow with $x$. You could get a better estimate by iterating the logarithmic integral function. Using this estimate I guess that $\pi_{10}(10^{100})\approx7.8\times10^{76}.$

Comment: Using the Prime Number Theorem also gives an extremely bad estimate when $\pi^n(x)$ is small.

Comment: @vukov: Agreed. That's another manifestation of $n$ growing with $x$.