# Prime twins and $ f(z) = \sum_p \frac{\ln(p) \space \ln(p+2)}{p^{z/2} \space (p+2)^{z/2}} $

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, conjectures, zeta-functions, twin-primes

Let $p$ be a prime such that $p+2$ is Also a prime.

Define

$$ f(z) = \sum_p \frac{\ln(p) \space \ln(p+2)}{p^{z/2} \space (p+2)^{z/2}} $$

For $z \neq 1 $ and $re(z) > 1$ this $f(z)$ always converges.

If there are infinitely many prime twins , and prime twins grow like $O (n * ln(n)^2 ) $ as is commonly believed , then clearly $f(1)$ diverges.

If there are only finitely many prime twins then $f(z)$ converges everywhere ; it would be an entire function.

For the remainder of this , let us assume there are infinitely many prime twins and they grow like $ O( n * \ln(n)^2 ) $.
Thus we assume $f(1)$ diverges.

Notice the similarity with the Riemann zeta function or prime zeta function.

So the main questions are :

1. where are the zero’s of $f(z) $ ?
2. How about analytic continuations ?  Can it be extended to the whole complex plane ? Do we need $re(z) > 0 $ ?
3. Do we have a critical line ? Or can a slight modification ( such as neglegting a few twins or a slightly different infinite sum ) lead to a critical line ?
4. Is $f(1)$ a pole or singularity ?
5. Do the zero’s have real part of 1/2 ? Do any have real part 1/2 ?

Large Numerical data suggests that

$$ \pi_2(n) = \int_2^n c_2 \cdot ln(x)^{-2} dx + O(n^{2+\epsilon}) (**) $$

Where O is big O notation, $c_2 $ is the prime twin constant and $\pi_2$ is the twin prime counting function. This is more or less an analogue of the Riemann hypothesis , which led to question 5) .

Maybe it matters If we assume $(**)$ or not to answer 1-5.
The situation is unclear.

Im fascinated by this function.
At the same time however, i wonder If this is the best analogue of the zeta function to study prime twins or not. Or the best function to study the twins.

I assume there are no special values known. ( this is not a main question , Just a thought )

Related to questions 1-5 and $(**)$

Is $f(z)(z-1)$ entire ??

——

Update

Tommy1729 sent me a message where he says that according to his estimates

$$ f(z) + 3/2 = 0 $$

Has infinitely many solutions with $ re(z) $ close to $ 1$ and close to $2/3$.

I was able to confirm the observation for twins up to 43 and the 4 first zero’s.

Could those values $1,2/3$ be the exact real parts ?

Do we have 2 critical lines for $ f(z) + 3/2 $ ?
 And What does that all imply ?
What is the meaning of that all ?

——

Comment: What’s the motivation behind this function? Do you have a link to an Arxiv or vixra, I’d be interested in reading it.

Comment: No papers have been written by me. @frogeyedpeas Also this function behaves like the harmonic series near z = 1 Just like the Riemann zeta ( under assumption (**) ) and seems more logical and practical then $ \sum p^{-z}$ or $\sum a_p z^p $ ( for Some seq of constants $a_p $ ).  Also I do not see the point of many Sums or products within the summand.

Comment: "If there are infinitely many prime twins then clearly f(1) diverges" Why?

Comment: Notice the updates.

Comment: I think $f(z) (z-1) \ln(z)^a $ for Some value a makes analytic continuation easier ...